# deep copying using copy constructor c++

Tags: c++, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I am trying to implement my own CString class. I am facing some problem in shallow copying the pointer.
Here is the class

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class myCString{
public:
    myCString(){
        m_value = NULL;
    }
    myCString(char* strParam){
        int len = length(strParam);
        m_value = new char[len+1];
        for(int i=0;i<len; i++)
        {
            m_value[i] = strParam[i];
        }
        m_value[len]='\0';

    }
    myCString(const myCString& obj)
    {
        int len = obj.length();
        m_value = new char[len+1];
        for(int i=0;i<len; i++)
        {
            m_value[i] = obj.m_value[i];
        }
        m_value[len]='\0';
    }
        myCString(const myCString *obj)
    {
        int len = obj->length();
        m_value = new char[len+1];
        for(int i=0;i<len; i++)
        {
            m_value[i] = obj->m_value[i];
        }
        m_value[len]='\0';
    }
     const int length() const
    {
        return length(m_value);
    }
    myCString operator=(myCString obj)
    {
        int i=0;
        int length= obj.length();
        m_value = new char[length + 1];
        for(;i<obj.length(); i++)
        {
            m_value[i] = obj.m_value[i];
        }
        m_value[length]='\0';
        return m_value;
    }

    ~myCString()
    {
        delete []m_value;
        m_value = NULL;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const myCString obj);
private:
    const int length(char* strParam)const
    {
        int i=0;
        while(strParam[i]!='\0'){
        i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
    char *m_value;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, myCString obj)
    {
        os<<obj.m_value;
        return os;
    }
```

and here is the main():

```
#include"myCString.h"
int main()
{
    myCString *ptr = new myCString("Hi! This is myCString\n");
    cout<<*ptr;
    myCString *ptr2 = ptr;
    delete ptr;
    cout<<*ptr2;
    delete ptr2;
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is when shallow copy happens; i know that writing

```
myCString *ptr2 = new myCString(ptr);
```

will fix the issue; but i want to keep the main function intact and make some changes in the class. 
Is there anyway i can do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How? You are directing a pointer to point at the same object as `ptr`. There is no copying happening here

Comment: `myCString *ptr2 = ptr;` invokes a copy on the type `myCString*` and not `myCString` so your constructor won't get called. If you wrote `myCString obj2 = ptr;` or `new myCString(ptr)` only then the copy ctor of `myCString` is used. Also allowing copy from a pointer makes very few sense and only adds to the confusion.

Comment: so, there is no way so that ptr2 and ptr have two different memory spaces?

Comment: Yes there is a way, allocate memory... the syntax `T *a = b;` will always copy a pointer (of type `T*`) and not its pointee however.

Comment: `ptr` and `ptr2` do occupy two different spaces in memory. However they are pointers and both pointing at the same memory location (where the object is)

Comment: Here's the obligatory [binky reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-pJlnpkLp0)...

Comment: ok... my bad... :) what i wanted to ask is; is there a way these two pointers become independant, so that even if i delete the 1st one, the 2nd one is still usable without changing the code in main()?

Comment: one more thing, what if i overload = operator? i tried doing that too, but that didn't help. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is to make a deep copy of the objekt in the line  `myCString *ptr2 = ptr`, 
 but this aim is not reachable by object's class programing, because this line only copies a pointer and does not involve the object's class.
 If you like to call the copy constructor, You must write as You suggested:
 `myCString *ptr2 = new myCString(ptr)`; 
 or You can write:

```
myCString mystr("Hi! This is myCString\n");
cout<<mystr;
myCString mystr2 =mystr;
cout<<mystr;
```

Another problem: calling function `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, myCString obj)` the
     copy operator `myCString(const myCString& obj)` is called for parameter obj. You should write

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const myCString& obj)
```

to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your
`myCString(char* strParam)` signature to

`myCString(const char* strParam)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; but that wont solve this issue right?